# What is the proper way to deal with data types that are somewhat related yet very different in utility?

Tags: javascript, xml

Good evening (or morning), everyone.

I'm currently working on a codebase for what is to become a forthcoming website's content "engine", where it will take in different types of standardized data (implemented with XML), parse it, and then generate content dynamically and accordingly.

The data itself also includes a list of context clues or helper objects for searching, comparing, analyzing, etc., which is being developed concurrently into a group as a data interaction layer and it is completely separate from the engine.

I'm under the impression that the engine should take care of all data (both content and contexts) initially and place those list of clues in an array within the engine object so that the interaction layer can utilize them later for its initialization and tools, for a rough example and some concepts (please excuse my way of formatting code)

```
var InteractionLayer = {

   Initialize: function () {

        if (Engine.Content.Contexts.length != 0) {

            this.IterateLength = (
                Engine.Content.Contexts.length);
            this.Iterate();
        } else {

            return 0;
        }
    },

    IterateResult: 0,
    IterateLength: 0,
    IterateFrame: 0,
    Iterate: function () {

        if (IterateResult == 0) {

            var Reflection = this;

            setTimeout(function () { Reflection.IterateStatus() }, 17);
        } else {

            // Paused.
            return 0;
        }
    },
    IterateStatus: function () {

        if (this.IterateFrame < this.IterateLength) {

            // Do something.

            this.IterateFrame += 1;
            this.Iterate();
        } else {

            // Done.

            this.IterateLength = 0;
            this.IterateFrame = 0;

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, it seems appropriate to completely separate content and contexts data from each other so that both the engine and the interaction layer may have its own array of data as needed--requesting the same data twice for parsing different sections just sounds very inefficient if indeed the interaction layer needed its own data.

Each generated content will have some embedded clues as what it is for post-processing with tools supplied by the interaction layer (possibly with few generated hidden input DOM objects). Nonetheless, I'm at a loss as to what the proper way is to deal with data types that are related yet will be used differently. There may be other solutions that are better than what I have considered and any help with this issue would be awesome.

Comment: Sounds more like you want an opinion, than help with your code. `IterateResult == 0` should be `this.IterateResult === 0`. I threw in the extra `=` in `===` which assures exact match versus truthy `==` match. Code should be reused when possible. Consider making separate instances, using `Object.create()` and a backward compatible counterpart, or change your JavaScript to Constructor function code.

Comment: Hmm, interesting suggestions for code improvement. Thanks, PHPglue. I'll definitely review those immediately. Nonetheless, I was afraid that my question would sound opinion-based but I was hoping there was some sort of a pattern that I could follow that is tried-and-true that would help me with this situation. The solutions that I provided so far were some that I have thought about already and were not to invoke subjective comparisons on what is better but on what is standard (maintenance and code expansion wise).